# Output int from string input

Tags: beginner, c, strings

This takes a string input like `1,2,3,4,5`, splits it using `,` delimiter, converts each char to int and output it in a single line like this : `12345`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* createIntArray(char* numbersInString, int* array_size);

int* createIntArray(char* numbersInString, int* array_size)
{
    char* token = strtok(numbersInString,",");
    int* numbersArray = malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
    int i = 0;

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        numbersArray[i] = (int)*token -'0';
        token = strtok(NULL,",");
        i++;
    }

    *array_size = i;
    return numbersArray;
}

int main(){
    char* stringNumbers = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    int* intArray;
    int arrayLength = 0;
    printf("Enter numbers\n");
    scanf("%s",stringNumbers);
    intArray = createIntArray(stringNumbers,&arrayLength);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < arrayLength;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",intArray[i]);
    }

    free(stringNumbers);
    free(intArray);
    return 0;
}
```

I know the code is super useless, but I'm starting to learn C and I wanted to see if my code was alright and if it complies to C coding standards.

Comment: I spy an [**integer overflow exploit**](http://phrack.org/issues/60/10.html)!

Comment: This would happen if I was happening to enter : `12379573853625767531596,1`. Is that it?

Comment: No, you would have to enter enough characters to fill up all of the buffers on the local stack, ~106-116 bytes/characters depending on the computer architecture.

Comment: Oh, not understanding what you mean means I should read your link :P

Comment: This is a more complicated topic for a beginner to understand.  Don't worry too much if you don't get the concept.  If you were to use this same code for a login application though, then I would have to write a full-fledged answer on the exploitation process and prevention of the overflow.

Comment: Alright, I won't worry about it too much for now, but I'll read about it anyway!

Comment: @syb0rg I don't see an exploit here. Heap corruption is possible though.

Comment: Here's a minor thing that I'm mentioning only because you tagged this beginner: consider declaring pointers like `int *i;`, just in case you ever try `int* x, y;` and wonder why `y` isn't a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things to consider, since this is a learning exercise. They don't really matter for your program, but maybe you'll avoid learning a few bad habits...

- `while(token != NULL)` would commonly be written `while(token)` instead.
- Learn about `const`.  Use it whenever you can.  It can make the meaning of the code clearer, and it can help the compiler find mistakes. Your `createIntArray` function could have parameters `char* const numbersInString` and `int* const array_size`, for example.
- Try to use a consistent style for naming things.  `numbersInString` is one style. `array_size` is a different one.  Either style works ok.  Mixing them adds a bit of confusion.
- `strtok` is an anti-favorite of mine.  It modifies the input string.  Sometimes that's fine, but you could do this task without modifying the input.  A function that works on a constant string will be useful in more places than a function that  alters the input to get the same result.

Comment: What could I use instead of `strtok`? When I looked on Google it is the one that seemed the most suited for my case

Comment: @TopinFrassi Use [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r).

Comment: `strtok_r` also modifies the input string.  I don't have a suggested one-size-fits-all replacement to suggest; it depends on the situation.  In this case, I might start with `sscanf` to find one integer at a time from the string.

Comment: This was too easy ahah

Comment: @GraniteRobert I know, but that is a standard thread-safe option for `strtok`.  Using `sscanf` to find one integer at a time would be inefficient.

Answer (score 6):

- Since you have `main()` below the other function, you don't need the prototype for that function.  It's only needed if `main()` is defined before a function that it calls.
- There's no need to declare a variable and then assign to it:

  > ```
  > int* intArray;
  > // ...
  > intArray = createIntArray(stringNumbers,&arrayLength);
  > ```

  Variables should just be initialized in the closest scope possible.  This will ease maintenance as you won't have to search for the declared variable elsewhere, such as if it's no longer in use.

  ```
  int* intArray = createIntArray(stringNumbers,&arrayLength);
  ```
- Instead of incrementing `i` in `createIntArray()`, why not just increment `array_size`?

  Plus, `i` is more commonly used as a `for` loop counter, which isn't the case here.  If someone were to take a glance at that `while` loop without further context, they may think that it should be a `for` loop instead.  By making this change, you'll remove that possible misconception *and* better communicate your exact intentions.

Comment: I'm so focused on figuring pointers out that I forget the basics of programming!! Though I didn't know about your first point, thanks!

Comment: @TopinFrassi: Forgive my shameless self-promoting, but if you're trying to figure out pointers [this might be of some use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114400/print-a-number-in-c-digit-by-digit/20114877#20114877). People seemed to like my explanation there :)

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple minor things I'd like to add to this: What if the string that is passed to `createIntArray` contains *more* than 100 ints? Currently, you're allocating 100 ints, regardless of how many you'll actually *need*. I'd choose to use a stack array as buffer, and `realloc` the dynamic memory in chunks. Then, I'd copy the buffer to this new memory (using `memcpy`).
I'd also change the type of `array_size` to `size_t`: it's unsigned, as a size should be, and it's more descriptive.

Before I start listing every single change I'd make, here's a re-written version of your function:

```
int* createIntArray(char* numbersInString, size_t* array_size)
{//string is not altered, use const
    char* token = strtok(numbersInString,",");
    //buffer array
    int buffer[100];
    int* numbersArray = NULL;//null ptr here
    int i = 0;
    //check if array_size is valid
    if (array_size == NULL)
        return NULL;//null-pointer!
    //initialize array_size to 0
    *array_size = 0;
    while(token)
    {
        buffer[i] = *token -'0';//no need to cast
        //or, if you #include <stdlib.h>
        buffer[i] = atoi(token);
        if (++i == 100)
        {//buffer is full
            *array_size += i;
            numbersArray = realloc(
                numbersArray,
                *array_size * sizeof *numbersArray
            );
            if (numbersArray == NULL)
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            //copy buffer
            memcpy(
                numbersArray + (*array_size - i),
                buffer,
                sizeof buffer
            );
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    if (i)
    {//add remainder of buffer
        *array_size += i;
        numbersArray = realloc(
            numbersArray,
            *array_size * sizeof *numbersArray
        );
        if (numbersArray == NULL)
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        memcpy(
            numbersArray + (*array_size - i),
            buffer,
            i * sizeof *buffer
        );
    }
    return numbersArray;
}
```

Ok, why did I change/add certain things:

- `*array_size = 0;`: The inital value of `array_size` should be 0, if you look at how/where I call `realloc`, it should be obvious why I did this.
- `*array_size += i;`: When the buffer is full, `++i` will be 100, and the memory allocated by `numbersArray` has do be adjusted, to hold `i` additional values, each of `sizeof *numbersArray`.
- `memcpy(numbersArray + (*array_size - i),arr, sizeof arr)`: This is the tricky bit (perhaps). The `numbersArray` could already hold 200 or 300 ints. Calling `memcpy` requires us to pass a (VALID!) pointer to the first block of memory that is actually available to write to. This is the `array_size` minus the size of the buffer (`i`). The source to copy from is, of course, the `buffer` array, and the amount of bytes to copy is, naturally, `sizeof buffer`.

When the `while` loop breaks, It's a simple matter of checking `i`'s value, to see if there are new values in the buffer, and adding those to the dynamic memory array.
The `memcpy` call here is a little bit different. If you pass `sizeof buffer` here, you will invoke undefined behaviour (due to heap corruption). Instead, because we've re-allocated `numbersArray` to hold just `i` ints more, you have to pass `i * sizeof *buffer` instead. Read this expression as *`i` times the size of whatever type `buffer` holds*. IE, if `i` is 10, memcpy will copy the number of bytes, required to store 10 ints. No more.

Whether you choose to use this code or not, a couple of tips I would *urge* you to take to heart:

- avoid `ptr = malloc(sizeof(type)*n)`, the safer, more common way to allocate memory is to use `ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr *n);`. If the type of `ptr` is changed, you don't have to worry about the `malloc`'s, `sizeof *ptr` is like saying *"size of whatever type ptr points to"*.
- Always check pointers, be it those that are returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`, or pointers that are passed to a function.
- perhaps unrelated: consider re-writing this function to return the array size (which allows you to return negatives to indicate errors), and instead take a `int **target_array` argument, along with a `size_t current_size`. so you can re-work this function to add values to an existing dynamic array, too.